# "this" keyword when implements multiple interface in Android

Tags: java, android, this, android-button

I know `this` keyword is a reference to the current object but I am confusing about when implements multiple interface in Android Application.

Ex. I create new `Button` like this:

```
public class Example extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

@Override
...
// override OnClick and OnTouch

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // 'this' refer to context in Activity
    Button button = new Button(this);

    // 'this' refer to OnClickListener
    button.setOnClickListener(this);

    // 'this' refer to OnTouchListener
    button.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

}
```

How program know what object to refer?

How program know must pass context in Activity as parameter when create new `Button` instead of `OnClickListener`?

Thanks.

Comment: `this` refers to the current object. Simple as that. You don't have a different object for each type you extend/implement; you have a single object that extends/implements all those types.

Comment: in each case this is still the current object. the implements keyword simply states that this object will respond to certain method calls

Comment: Good question, but really unclear.

Comment: 1.In Outer Class you directly use "this" reference
2.In Inner Class Or Abstract Class implementation Or Interface implementation use "classname.this" reference

Comment: @Haresh I don't think you're totally right. `classname.this` is only useful for inner classes. How would you use that for abstract classes or interface implementations (whatever that means)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to your `Example`.

Regarding what your wrote here:

```
// 'this' refer to context in Activity
Button button = new Button(this);

// 'this' refer to OnClickListener
button.setOnClickListener(this);

// 'this' refer to OnTouchListener
button.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Actually, they all refer to an `Example`, which *is* an `Activity`, `OnClickListener`, and `OnTouchListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Extending classes, implementing interfaces is a major part of Object Oriented Programming. Lets say you have class called Car, and several interfaces, Accelerate, Brake, Steer. When Car implements those interfaces, it means it can do those things. Then you can say myCar.brake();, or myCar.steer("left"); or myCar.accelerate(10);. You can change myCar to thisCar, or simply this, because all those car share same behaviour.

Oracle has it's Really Big Index, and since Android is based on Java, it's quite decent reference point. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html